# Taylor expansion in $4D$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)=(x_2,-x_1,\sqrt 2 x_4 + x_1^3,-\sqrt 2x_3+x_3x_4^2)$ be a vector valued function from $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$. Would anyone help me expand it up to and including the third term in its McLauren expansion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Mac Laurin expansion of the components of $f$

In your setting

$$f=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):=(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$$

with $f_i=f_i(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. For any $n=1,2,3,4$, the MacLaurin expansion of $f_n$ up to third order (we expand around the point $0:=(0,0,0,0)$) is given by

$$f_n(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=f_n(0)+\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_i}(0)x_i+
\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4 \frac{1}{2!}\frac{\partial^2 f_n}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(0)x_i x_j+\\
+\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{1}{3!}\frac{\partial^3 f_n}{\partial x_k\partial x_j\partial x_i}(0) x_ix_jx_k+O(\|x\|^4),$$

i.e. a lot of partial derivatives! Fortunately $f_n$ is a polynomial in the variables $x_1,\dots,x_4$: this means that it is a $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^4)$ function and the Schwartz Lemma applies, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial^2 f_n}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial^2 f_n}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$$

for all $i,j=1,\dots, 4$ and, consequently,

$$\frac{\partial^3 f_n}{\partial x_k\partial x_j\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial^3 f_n}{\partial x_a\partial x_b\partial x_c}, $$

for any $(a,b,c)\in\{i,j,k\}$.

- Some computations

Now the structure of the Mac Laurin expansion is clear. All we need is to compute some derivatives. I will begin with some computations: you can finish them easily. Mine are:

$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}=1 $$
$$\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}=-1 $$
$$\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1}=3x_1^2 $$
$$\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_4}=\sqrt{2} $$
$$\frac{\partial f_4}{\partial x_4}=2x_3x_4 $$
$$...$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f_3}{\partial^2 x_3}=6x_3 $$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f_4}{\partial^2 x_4}=2x_3$$
$$...$$

To arrive at the answer, please note that:

1. all partial derivative must be evaluated at $0=(0,0,0,0)$ (so really few of them survive)
2. The components of $f$ are polynomials of low degree in the variables $x_i$. Even fewer contributions "survive" to the application of 3 partial derivatives.

With all these information, it should be easy for you to fill in the gaps. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you, Avitus. You only need to divide the $n$-th cofficient by $n!$

Comment: Since the polynomial is of degree $3$, should I not get the truncated Taylor expansion to be exactly equal to $f$? I am getting $f_{3,111}=6$, and $f_{4,344}=2$. The rest of the third partial derivatives are zero. The third term in the expansion is then  $\frac{1}{3!}(0,0,6x_1^3,2x_3x_4^2)$ instead of $\frac{1}{3!}(0,0,6x_1^3,6x_3x_4^2)$ as expected. Have I made a mistake. Did I get the right result?

Comment: @Ivan you are right! I correct the typo: thanks for finding it :)

Comment: @Ivan this is a good point. All $f_i$'s are polynomials. As we compute the expansion at $0$, the only contribution that survives is the partial derivative of degree equal to the one of the polynomial itself. $f_{3,111}=\frac{6}{3!}=1$, and $f_3=\frac{6}{3!}f_{3,111} x_1^3+\frac{1}{1!}f_{3,4}x_4$. In summary, the only contributions for $f_3$ are $f_{3,4}$ and $f_{3,111}$. You can see this considering that $f_3$ is a sum of $g(x_4)+h(x_3)$ with no mixed contributions (like $x_3x_4$ etc...)

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if I had the right answer. I am somehow getting non-zero remainder. The nill term in the expansion is zero, the first is the linear part, the second is zero, and the third one is as above. Why do I have non-zero remainder?

Comment: @Ivan it is because you have more than one $f_{4,344}$ partial der. contribution: you have exactly 3 of them. If you choose as first derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}$, then you can only get $\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_3\partial x_4\partial x_4}$. If you begin by choosing $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_4}$, then you can continue with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}$, or with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_4}$. Applying the 3rd and last remaining derivative, you always arrive at $\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_3\partial x_4\partial x_4}$ (by Schwartz Lemma), but 3 times, and $2\frac{3}{3!}=1$.